# SQL query to return all items who have a particular id

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

I need help with creating a query.

I need all items from one table of items whose id matches the chosen one.

Some items are part of a group, if so they have a groupId not null, which is the primary key to another table.

I want to return the id of the item, the description of the item, and if it is part of a group, to return the group description of that item, which is in the other table.

Comment: Paste the relevant schema into the question please.

Comment: Why did you tag this question with three different RDBMS implementations?

Comment: Cause I don't mind what implementation the answer is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the little information you gave in the post I tried to put together an answer.
If you notice that I missed anything, just add some details and I'll "fix" the answer ;-)

```
SELECT ITEMID, 
       ITEMDESC, 
       Isnull(GROUPDESC, '') GroupDesc 
FROM   ITEMTABLE T1 
       LEFT JOIN GROUPTABLE T2 
              ON T1.GROUPID = T2.GROUPID 
WHERE  ITEMID = @Chosen
```

Comment: Exactly right, worked like a charm! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes, if `groupId` is `NULL`, the `group_description` will be `NULL`:

```
SELECT ID, 
       DESCRIPTION, 
       GROUP_DESCRIPTION 
FROM   TABLE1 
       LEFT JOIN TABLE2 
              ON TABLE1.GROUPID = TABLE2.GROUPID 
WHERE  ID = YOUR_ID
```

Hope it helps!